# Generic type with loose conditions

Tags: c#, generics

I'm building an application that supports plugins over a generic type of data. Problem is, I can't seem to specify a generic condition that allows everything I need to pass through, here's the details of the code:

```
abstract public class PluginObject<ManagedType>
abstract public class Plugin<EditedType> where EditedType : PluginObject<Object>
```

The `<Object>` here is the problem, when I create my classes and plugins, I'll create models to handle the data aspect of the plugin. To this end, my first plugin has many items to manage and I can't really create a sub class of them all, so I ended up create an interface `IOrderObject` that doesn't contain anything.

Therefore, I ended up with:

1. `SynchronizableObject`
2. `TripRoute`
3. `TripRouteDirection`
4. `ITripObject` (Interface implemented into #2 and #3)

This way I can do:

```
public class RoutePluginObject<ManagedType> : Activis.Framework.Admin.PluginObject<ManagedType>
public class RouteManagementPlugin : Activis.Framework.Admin.Plugin<RoutePluginObject<Transdev.Limocar.iTripObject>>
```

And it is accepted, but the problem is that `ITripObject` is an interface not an object, so it can be converted to `PluginObject<Object>`.

So my question, is there a way to specify a condition that would allow something similar to this:

```
abstract public class Plugin<EditedType> where EditedType : PluginObject<Any>
```

This way, interfaces or objects could be provided by I don't really care about this condition; all I want is that my `Plugin`'s `editedtype` be a `PluginObject` of anything possible.

---

**EDIT**

Having better results with the covariance but still getting an error, i haven't seen anything about the PluginObject inheritance in your examples (Matias), here is what i did:

```
public interface IPluginObject<out ManagedType>
abstract public class Plugin<EditedType> where EditedType : IPluginObject<EditedType>
public class RoutePluginObject : Activis.Framework.Admin.IPluginObject<TripRoute>
public class RouteManagementPlugin : Activis.Framework.Admin.Plugin<RoutePluginObject>
```

But i still get errors at the RouteManagementPlugin with:

> The type 'Transdev.Limocar.Admin.RoutePluginObject' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'EditedType' in the generic type or method
>   'Activis.Framework.Admin.Plugin'. There is no implicit
>   reference conversion from 'Transdev.Limocar.Admin.RoutePluginObject'
>   to
>   'Activis.Framework.Admin.IPluginObject'

Unless i misunderstood covariance (which is probably the case) i seem to have followed your example clearly, still not getting it working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a second generic parameter:

```
abstract public class PluginObject<ManagedType> {}
abstract public class Plugin<EditedType, OtherType> where EditedType : PluginObject<OtherType>
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make the code redundant then? I'd specify the condition as one of the types, so i'd type in the same type twice to automatically accept the condition?

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Yep.  If it was a generic method it could be inferred, and you could avoid it, but that won't work for generic arguments to a class.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin Your other option would be for `PluginObject` to be an interface, rather than an abstract class, in which case you may be able to make it covarient, and `PluginObject<Object>` would work as you intended.  That may or may not be an option though, given the unspecified context.

Comment: Couldn't make covariance work correctly and since i really need to make this move on, i implemented your solution and flagged your answer. Covariance COULD have been a solution but i couldn't make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need **covariance**.

That is, generic parameter can be *downcasted*.

Covariance and contravariance can be only used in *interfaces* and *delegates* generic parameters.

In your case, you should implement `PluginObject` as an interface:

```
public interface IPluginObject<out T>
```

This will enable your code to do so:

```
public abstract class Plugin<TEdited> where TEdited : IPluginObject<TEdited>
```

At the end of the day, say you've a type `Person` and a derived type `Employee`. `Person` implements `IPluginObject<out T>`. Then, thanks to covariance, next code is valid:

```
IPluginObject<object> myPluginObject = new Employee();
```

Finally, of course, you can do this:

```
public class MyPlugin : Plugin<Employee>
{
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Check this MSDN article for further details on this topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Comment: This looks like it, since it's time to clock out, i'll look at this tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Hi, please see the EDIT in my post, something still isn't working